# Can't run android project from my bitbucket repo

Tags: git, android-studio

I created android project and push it to the bitbucket repo.

On my computer everything working.
But when my team try to download the repo and check how it works, there are no any configuration, so they can't run android app, because there is no any configuration.

This is my git ignore. It seems some files were not downloaded... I am stuck, please help me.

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

after git ls-tree HEAD command I got this

```
100644 blob b583e64cae82d4c6dbb7ef16d30bbdd059f8b45e    .gitignore
040000 tree 61621979dc6feabeeef76b9271b156e5fc7e6cb1    .idea
040000 tree 6d444fd6d73a34dc1fe955afa002aad2001c4900    app
100644 blob 1d3591c8a4c9c29578c36c87f80c05a6aea3ee3f    gradle.properties
040000 tree aa9459848258002470ba61d1058a6aac7208186f    gradle
100755 blob 9d82f78915133e1c35a6ea51252590fb38efac2f    gradlew
100644 blob aec99730b4e8fcd90b57a0e8e01544fea7c31a89    gradlew.bat
100644 blob e7b4def49cb53d9aa04228dd3edb14c9e635e003    settings.gradle
100644 blob b4af0228d96a84312eefe290018418ccbead7fe5    test.iml
```

Comment: Have you added all yoiur files and commited them? `git status`

Comment: Yes, I added all changes all files. I tried to push this project into github - and after donwloading zip the same issue - I need to add configuration

Comment: Are there any file which are missing?  Type git ls-tree HEDA

Comment: I have noriced that my build.gradle is empty, but when I added all stuff like in my project, nothing has changed

Comment: Those are the files which are committed.  Do you miss any file there

Comment: Yes, I dont see build.gradle here, but I have added it manually into project folder and result the same

Comment: So the files is in one of your .gitignored list. What OS are you on?

Comment: My operation system is MAC OS

Comment: so you can execute: 'updatedb' 'locate .gitignore' and search all your files to verify that its not in any of them

Comment: Have never heard about it, could you explain more? Actually I thought delete .gitignore and push all files...

Comment: This command is building your local file index on your machine and later on you can search the entire computer for any desired file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out! The problem was that I had a global gitignore (.gitignore_global) whith build.gradle ignore. In order to delete it try this:

1. Go to the home directory in terminal
2. Type `ls -la`    -this command show all files (I saw that I have
   .gitignore_global)
3. `rm -Rf .gitignore_global`  delete this file
4. `rm -Rf .hgignore_global` delete this file

So now my git see all changes in build.gradle file